# How long does it actually take to travel from Tishbi to the Kerith Ravine?

Tags: the-days-of-elijah, john-noble

In Chapter Six of *[The Days of Elijah](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Days_of_Elijah.html?id=TUTJzAEACAAJ&source=kp_book_description)*, when Elijah is told to go to the Kerith Ravine, the following description is given:

> The Kerith Ravine on the east bank of the Jordan, he knew the spot, maybe a day from Tishbi.

Yet in the very next chapter, when Elijah thinks about leaving the ravine to go home to Tishbi, the journey is described as only half as long:

> Suddenly, he was glad he hadn't gone home. The temptation had been getting to him the last few weeks. Tishbi was little more than a half day's walk from the ravine. He could have gone there, said hi to his parents, and still been back in time to enjoy his supper with the ravens.

Is this simply an authorial mistake?

Is it possible that both figures are correct? (E.g. it actually takes twice as long to travel from Tishbi to the Kerith Ravine than from the Kerith Ravine to Tishbi.)

I suppose that it is possible that both figures are approximations, and the actual distance can be loosely approximated as both a day's journey and a half day's journey, but then why not be consistent in the approximation?

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/what-and-where-is-the-kerith-ravine

Answer (score 1):

I’m not familiar with the work, but just from a language perspective I’m reading this as, when he was told to go he didn’t know how long it would take, so *estimated* it as ‘maybe’ a day, but once he had traveled there he *knew* from his own experience, or had otherwise since learned, that it was only just over half a day.

Regardless of how he came by the improved information, the difference between the two statements suggests that he did.

Comment: Thisis a nice approach, though I don’t think it works in this case. I probably should have mentioned it in the question, but in Chapter Six he was actually traveling to the ravine from somewhere else, not Tishbi.